# how to use json files in a dictionary in spark map function?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am using pyspark.

I want to load a regular jsonfile say "region-polygon-mapping" file containing region names and its polygons on Google map.

When I process another dataset RDD, I want to use the "region-polygon-mapping" in the map function, say to test if point in RDD is in the region by the polygon.

The question is how can I use json as a regular file in RDD map function. the json file is very small, the spark does not allow to use json as the second rdd because we can not user a rdd in another rdd's map function. Here is the error if I do it.

pickle.PicklingError: Could not pickle object as excessively deep recursion required.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with python or pyspark but I'll try to answer this.

I assume you're trying to use one dataset for lookups while processing another dataset? Correct me if I'm wrong.

To do so, you'll need to implement joins. A small example below,

Say you have a small dataset with countryName and currency. You have to process user logs that contains userID, countryName and other info. You need to find what user will have what currency.

You'll need to join on countryName.

If the first dataset is an RDD, caching it may be useful.

Let me know if this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In the absence sample data, I am assuming your json file has a {key: value} structure. Either way, you can load your json file into a structure that mirrors the json file using the json module. For a file of the format {key: value}, the data will be loaded into python as a dictionary. Once you have that, you can very easily use that dictionary to map your rdd. For example, if your `rdd` is a distributed list of regions, and the region-polygon-mapping is intended to map the regions to polygons, then the following code will give you the output of the map:

```
import json

with open('region-polygon-mapping.json','r') as json_data:
    rp_map=json.load(json_data)

mappedrdd=rdd.map(lambda x:rp_map[x])
```

The `mappedrdd` will now be an rdd of polygons. This may leave off some details, but should be easily modifiable for your use case.